# Javascript AMD pattern confusion - persisting property values

Tags: javascript, requirejs

So I am trying to get my head around the javascript AMD pattern using [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/). My experience with JS is limited and no doubt this is what is hampering me. I would not be surprised if I am pointed in the direction of "JS for Dummies". If anyone can bear to help me with this I would be VERY grateful.

I have defined a module called "security" which has the following definition - cut down a bit.

```
define(['services/storage'], function(storage) {

var security = {
    authToken: {},
    loadAuthToken: loadAuthToken,
    saveAuthToken: saveAuthToken,
};

return security;

function saveAuthToken(token) {
    if (token) {
        storage.save("DiffusrAuthToken", token);
        security.authToken = token;
    }     
};

function loadAuthToken() {       
    if (security.authToken.expires) {
        return security.authToken;
    } else {
        var token = storage.load("DiffusrAuthToken");
        security.authToken = token;
        return token;
    }
};
})
```

Essentially I want to save the state of some values defined in the module, in the case above, the `authToken`. This is so that when other modules *require* this module I don't have to go to `localStorage` to get it. The only way I can get this to work is by defining a property of the return object, and setting this to an empty object initially. This does not seem satifactory, because I do not want to expose it directly to other modules as they could change it.

The non-AMD way would be to define an object in the global scope and attach properties to it. BUT, I thought the whole point of AMD was to avoid this.

**Question**: How, generally, should I set values in modules that can be accessed from other modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you don't export in a module cannot be accessed outside the module but is still available within the module closure. For example, you can create a var but never attach it as a property of the `security` export object. You can create specific accessor methods to the export object that can access this private variable only in a way that you want users of the module to, as you have done with your `saveAuthToken` and `loadAuthToken` methods.

```
define(['services/storage'], function(storage) {

var authToken;  // private to security module

function saveAuthToken(token) {
    if (token) {
        storage.save("DiffusrAuthToken", token);
        authToken = token;  // store to private variable
    }     
};

function loadAuthToken() {       
    if (authToken.expires) {
        return authToken;
    } else {
        var token = storage.load("DiffusrAuthToken");
        authToken = token;
        return token;
    }
};

// export contains no reference to authToken
var security = {
    loadAuthToken: loadAuthToken,
    saveAuthToken: saveAuthToken,
};

return security;

});
```

Comment: Fantastic - so simple it is embarrassing! Just to be clear though - what is the lifetime of the private var? Does require.js keep the module in memory so any time another module uses the security module, the value is still assigned to the private variable?

Comment: It will survive as long as there is a reference to the module. You can remove the reference using [undef](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef), but if any other modules have `security` as a dependency then the module closure will remain alive.