# How to use Object literal as requirejs module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to get my head around the javascript AMD pattern using requireJS. I'm very new to object oriented programming and also new to requireJS. I'd hope some one can help me here.

I defined a test module called 'module3' with object literal:

```
define([], function () {
    var _name = 'this is a test3';
    var returnedModule3={
        name:'test',
        getName:getName
    }
    function getName() {
            return _name;
        }
    return returnedModule3;

});
```

However in the main.js file when I call this module after the file is loaded, I get an error in firebug saying "**TypeError: module3ref is not a constructor**". Below you will see the code in my main file:

```
// Load modules and use them
require(['myModule/module3'], function(module3ref){
    // do something with the loaded modules
    var module3 = new module3ref();
        console.log("module3.getName:"+module3.getName()); 
});
```

Does this mean we cannot use object literal to create module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried on my side. Try this:

```
define([], function () {
  var _name = 'this is a test3';
  var returnedModule3 = function(){
    this.name = 'test';
    this.getName = getName
  }
  function getName() {
    return _name;
  }
  return returnedModule3;    
});
```

**Note**: `this` should be attached to each property within `returnedModule3` so as to be accessed from outside/other JS file otherwise it become private to function and you will get error `object has no method getName`.

**Issue with your code:** In your code, you were trying to create an instance of object.

**Another Approach (EXPORTING OBJECT) :**
If you want to export `Object` as it is like your `returnedModule3` then must define `main.js` as:

```
require(['module3'], function(module3ref){
  // do something with the loaded modules
  console.log("module3.getName:"+module3ref.getName());
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code in a new module4 file and adapted the main file accordingly; but i still get the same type of error. I checked- my file structure is fine

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm just experiementing with different methods. This updated solution should work as I have tried it in module 1 and 2. It would be greate if you can explain a bit why the other method is not working. I did see in another post, they used the same approach to create the object security. see link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058286/javascript-amd-pattern-confusion-persisting-property-values?newreg=a0f6e1dd8512496988c179ca850eba3b

Comment: Would you be kindly able to give an example on how to use module3 in this case?

Comment: Please check my updated solution. You can use 'module3' like that. You can call 'name' as 'console.log("module3.name: " + module3ref.name);' and 'getName' as 'console.log("module3.getName: " + module3ref.getName());'. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I tried your new code; and it works perfect. I understand it better now. What confused me is that in the MDN doc 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects'. Using object initializers is listed as 1 way of creating a new object. I'm getting a little bit confused on creating object and object instance.

Comment: @Diezeit: Try to accept the answer if you found helpful/ got your solution. This would help others :)

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting your question's title literally: [RequireJS can turn object literals directly into AMD modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defsimple), e.g.:

```js
define({
  getName: function() {
    return 'this is a test3';
  },
  name: 'test'
})
```

However, with this pattern it's not possible for one property to refer to its "neighbours" (but that's a limitation of JS object literal syntax, not RequireJS itself).